# ¿Por qué en esta inserción, me muestra la siguiente ventana de error?

Tags: php, sql

```
INSERT INTO ticket(
              id_Ticket
              ,estado
              ,nom_Vendedor
              ,nom_Cliente
              ,rut_Cliente
              ,region
              ,ciudad
              ,comuna
              ,direccion
              ,courier
              ,nom_Contacto
              ,tel_Contacto
              ,not_Venta
              ,fec_Emision
              ,despacho
              )
    VALUES (
        '5000001'
       ,'Ingresado' 
       ,'Sin vendedor'
       ,'FERNANDA DÍAZ' 
       ,'Sin rut' 
       ,'METROPLITANA'
       ,'Sin especificar' 
       ,'Sin especificar'
       ,'Lautaro    (Cross-Docking) 9202' 
       ,'Sin courier'
       ,'FERNANDA DÍAZ'
       ,'Sin telefono contacto'
       ,'80998'
       ,'2022-06-15T16:15:27'
       ,'Para despacho');
       WHERE ( not_Venta = 22111);
```

La cosa es que aun saliendo el siguente error  Se inserta a la bd.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Y bueno quisiera saber el porque sale ese error es por la version o es
> un error de sintaxis?. Actualemten estoy usando el gesto de heidisql con cone mysql

Comment: Ese WHERE parece un resto de alguna otra parte, pues si te fijas, la sentencia INSERT termina justo antes del WHERE, delimitada por el punto y coma (**`;`**).  Elimina el WHERE y lo que venga a continuación y debería funcionarte bien.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una instrucción "INSERT" no puede incluir un "WHERE", es lo que te está intentado decir el mensaje de error, o si lo que quieres hacer es realizar una consulta después de hacer la inserción, te faltó el "SELECT * FROM" antes del "WHERE".

Puedes consultar la documentación [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)